# Differences between index/_stats size and du -h size in elasticsearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch, size, storage, du

I have a quick question:

I create random JSON files and send them to elasticsearch.
When I check the sizes of the files using du -h in my centos machine and when I check the stats in the _stats section I get major differences between the results.
for example:

file number--------du -h size ------ /_stats

100 --------------- 404 kb ---------- 297 kb

1000 ------------- 4096 kb -------- 1200 kb

3000 ------------- 12 MB ----------- 3.3 MB

Now is it reasonable that storing somthing in elastic is so much smaller than on linux machine?
Why is the gap is so big?

Comment: May you please tell how exactly do you measure `du -h`? Is it the size of sent jsons on disk?

Answer (score 0):

You give very little information, so we have to guess much.

You might talk about many JSONs of equal structure which represent documents in the ElasticSearch.  Then each JSON would repeat the information about the structure.  Then you would have in each JSON e. g. `{ "first_name": <X>, "last_name": <Y>, "phone": <Z> }` while in the ElasticSearch DB the structure is stored once per *index*, i. e. all documents share the structure, so only the various `<X>`, `<Y>`, and `<Z>` values need to be stored.

Naturally this is way smaller.

Also, `du` gives you the *disk usage* which is typically *more* than the *data size* because in file systems you allocate whole blocks (mostly to speed up things) so there always is a certain amount of overhead.  In a very bad case of lots of file contains just a few bytes each, each file uses a complete block, blowing up the *disk usage* by a significant factor.  For 20-bytes-files in a file system with blocks of 8192 bytes the factor will be ~400!